# Toeplitz operator and compctly supported symbol

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that Toeplitz Operator is compact if its symbol is compactly supported.

I trying to solve this problem from yesterday but i am not able to conclude any thing. This result i need in the proof of another big proof. could any one please give me some hint? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Could you define the Toeplitz operator and symbols?

Comment: Toeplitz operator on the Bergman space( collection of holomorphic function on D and square integrable with respect to area measure dA.) is defined as P(qf) where p is orthogonal projection from L2(D, dA) onto Begrman space q is symbol which is  some L infinity function on Disk and f is holomorphic square integrable function on D.